# Introduction to Linear Algebra (Strang) Challenge Question

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products, orthogonality

I've been studying from Gilbert Strang's 1993 Linear Algebra text, and right in the first chapter, I've found a problem on dot products whose answer in the back is tough for me to make sense out of...

Question:

> Pick any numbers that add to x + y + z = 0. Find the angle between your vector v = (x, y, z) and the vector w = (z, x, y). Challenge Question: Explain why (v · w) / ||v||||w|| is always -1/2.

The former part is easy. I found cos(angle) = -1/2 using v = (-1, -1, 2).

Answer given for the latter part:

> ...Write v · w = xz + yz + xy as (1/2)(x + y + z)<sup>2</sup> - (1/2)(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup>) whis is (-1/2)(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup>).

I tried rewriting it as suggested, which could make sense of that long middle term. It's is the final phrase "which is.." that throws me off.

Help so appreciated!

Comment: $x+y+z=0$ so the first term is zero.

Comment: The given hypothesis considers vectors $(x,y,z)$ with  $x+y+z=0$, hence the simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that $v\cdot w = xz+yz+xy = \frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)^2 - \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ we then have $$\frac{v\cdot w}{\|v\| \|w\|}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)^2 - \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac{0-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}=-\frac{1}{2}.$$